# Clicking link in :hover element sticks when using :focus-within

Tags: css

I'm creating a dropdown menu in an Angular web app where the header is a separate component. The links will change the content in the 'content body' and thus the header does not get 'refreshed'.

The issue im having is the dropdown will 'stick' when clicking the anchor element if :focus-within is set. For example: https://codepen.io/una/pen/eMaBgX (this is taken from https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/)

If you remove the line:

```
ul li:focus-within > ul,
```

the dropdown won't stick.

How do you stop the dropdown from sticking when clicking a link in the dropdown? Thanks

Comment: Don't you just do exactly as you said -- remove the line `ul li:focus-within > ul`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Then i cant use the :focus-within selector. Was hoping there was a way i could prevent the sticking without removing the selector.